Scrape react created webpage with class table in nested div with selenium and python
I am looking for a way to get table data from https://anmalan.gavlepistol.se/competition/653/roster
I want what is inside of each class=rv-squad", class="rv-squad-header full" and class="rv-participant". But everything below  just returns an empty list!?
The code I tried:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://anmalan.gavlepistol.se/competition/653/roster')

time.sleep(5)

print(driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'root'))

print(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'div.rv-squad-header.full'))


your code is almost just load website, work more on data extraction

You can use their REST APIs to get all data, e.g.:
import requests

competition_url = "https://dev.bitnux.com/anmalan/competition/653"
squad_url = "   https://dev.bitnux.com/anmalan/schedules/{schedule_id}/squad"

competition_data = requests.get(competition_url).json()

print(competition_data["name"])
print()
for e in competition_data["events"]:
    squad_data = requests.get(squad_url.format(schedule_id=e["schedule"])).json()
    for s in squad_data:
        if len(s["entries"]) == 0:
            continue
        print(s["time"])
        for ent in s["entries"]:
            print(f'{ent["name"]:<25} {ent["organization"]:<45} {ent["division"]}')
        print()

Prints:
Fyristräffen

08:00:00
Anders Johansson          Pistolklubben Ena                             C
Stefan Lind               Uppsala Handeldvapenförening                  C
Carl Mancini              Uppsala Handeldvapenförening                  C
Gary Nelson               Uppsala Handeldvapenförening                  C
Magnus Malmlund           Upplands Väsby Pistolskytteklubbb             C
Jonas Malm                F 16 Pistolklubb                              B
Michael Jelseus           Uppsala Handeldvapenförening                  C
Peter Åberg               Lunda Skf Pistolsektionen                     C

08:09:00
Jonas Strandman           Västerås Pistolskyttar                        R
Gunnar Larsson            Roslagens Pistolskyttar                       A
Johan Brundin             F 16 Pistolklubb                              A
Andreas Larsen            Västerås Pistolskyttar                        R
Bengt Andersson           F 16 Pistolklubb                              A
Bengt Pettersson          Västerås Pistolskyttar                        R
Carl Foberg               Mälarhöjdens Pistolskyttar                    A

...

